# Getting the updated record after a Persistent update

Tags: haskell, yesod

At the moment, if I try to do this inside a handler:

```hs
newPerson <- runDB $ update personId [PersonAge =. 27]
```

`newPerson` will have the type `()`. It seems that `update` doesn't yield any value, so if I want to get the updated entity, I need to do this:

```hs
newPerson <- runDB $ do
    update personId [PersonAge =. 27]
    get personId
```

Which results in `newPerson` having type `Maybe Person`, and some additional code to handle the `Nothing` case (or using `fromJust`). Is there a way to bypass the issue? *Should* there be? To me it makes sense for `update` to return the updated record, but should it really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` returns `()`, use [`updateGet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/1.2.3.0/doc/html/Database-Persist-Class.html#v%3aupdateGet).

Comment: The reason being of course that the update might be further altered (or added to or cancelled) by the underlying database. So, update can't reliably return anything without a (comparatively expensive) database read afterwards.

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks! Are there parallelism implications as well using either of these methods?

Comment: Nothing I can think of - apart from whatever the underlying db might impose.